# Python Similar Code Different Output

Tags: python

In the python interpreter I enter the following code:

```
params = {"server":"mpilgrim", "database":"master", "uid":"sa", "pwd":"secre
t"}

print "&".join("%s_%s" % (i,y) for i,y in params.items())
```

And, understandably, I get the following output:

```
pwd_secret&database_master&uid_sa&server_mpilgrim
```

But when I run the the following code:

```
for i,y in params.items():
    print "&".join("%s_%s" % (i,y))
```

I get this strange output:

```
p&w&d&_&s&e&c&r&e&t
d&a&t&a&b&a&s&e&_&m&a&s&t&e&r
u&i&d&_&s&a
s&e&r&v&e&r&_&m&p&i&l&g&r&i&m
```

Both code blocks seem to do the same thing. Why is the output different?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are using a generator expression to create a sequence of strings like 'pwd_secret', between which are interpolated '&'.

In the second case, you are calling join on each string like `'pwd_secret'`; strings are a type of sequence, so join does what it does, which is place the separator between each element of the sequence passed to it.

Answer (score 3):

`str.join` works on sequence. On the first piece of code it's working on a sequence of strings, while on the second piece it's working on one only string per loop. Strings are sequences (of characters) themselves, so...

```
>>> " ".join(["Hello", "world!"])
'Hello world!'
>>> " ".join("Hello world!")
'H e l l o   w o r l d !'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first case expanded is actually this:

```
temp_list = list()
for i,y in params.items():
   temp_list.append('%s_%s' % (i,y))
print '&'.join(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The string method `join` operates on a string, and takes an iterable as an argument. In the second example, the iterable you're passing is a string, equivalent to:

```
print '&'.join('pwd_secret')
```

Which comes out with each letter joined by an ampersand:

```
p&w&d&_&s&e&c&r&e&t
```

Answer (score 1):

THe first case works as you expect - join each tuple with an &.

In the second case, you have:

```
print "&".join("%s_%s" % (i,y))
```

Which, for the first item (for example), would do:

```
print "&".join("pwd_secret")
```

A string is an iterable, so it would join each character in the string with &, giving the output shown.